# React Native app crashes immediately on device but works on simulator?

Tags: android, react-native

I have an Expo React-Native app that works fine on the simulator but crashes immediately when on a device in release mode. I don't see anything in the crashes and ANR errors section of my app. What can I do to debug this issue?

What I use to test on the simulator

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

What I use to build the release

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Comment: Install it on a device and run it after enabling [usb debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) and check the crash traces in [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)

Comment: Or you could install flipper https://fbflipper.com/ and check the crash log from flipper

Comment: dear @JamesAnderbard, please add more information

Comment: I installed it on my phone and connected via usb debugging and found an error in the logcat: now working through the remaining errors

Comment: Currently getting the following error and not sure how to solve for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539379/react-native-error-project-with-path-expo-modules-core-could-not-be-found-in/70540742#70540742

Comment: Please include the error printed on crash..

Answer (score 0):

here there are some tips to you :

1-
Currently react-native-gesture-handler has to be imported before everything for the release build to work without crashing.

Add this line at the very top of index.js:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Then try to clean and rebuild the release again.

2- `AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', App);`
when it actually should have been like this

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

3- You should put --minify=false in extraPackagerArgs in android/app/build.gradle

as some of the classes/functions/methods might be ignored and not included in the release build if the compiler thinks its not used. In your case, the compiler might not have included expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController or the whole expo library.

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ],
];
```

4- it can be caused duplicate assets or android bundle , follow [this instruction](https://medium.com/@devesu/react-native-android-release-build-crash-on-device-14f2c9eacf18)

5- if none of the steps works , try to debug with Flipper , follow the instruction from [here](https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/react-native/)

Answer (score 0):

I had once a similar situation. I used a library to create uuid's and that lib used nodeJs crypto that was not available on every android device.