# React-Native error Task :expo:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am getting an error running the following in my React Native project with Expo. I have tried different versions of Expo and have deleted and recreated the node_modules and package-lock.json files.

```
./gradlew bundleRelease --stacktrace
```

```
> Task :expo:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (16, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (30, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (57, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (63, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/anderbard/Development/cloversocial/MyApp/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileReleaseKotlin'.
```

Do I need an even older version of Expo? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try downgrading the expo version and check.

Comment: That worked combined with deleting the android and ios and running the expo prebuild

Answer (score -2):

Just deleting the Android and iOS folders and re-creating them with expo eject worked for me. Upon review of what changed in the android folder, there are a lot of files that are very different in Expo 44, compared to 42, which is probably why it won't build.